# How can I check existence of temporary table and create it using INTO statement in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, temp-tables

I ve been using this formula in SQL Server since day 1:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#t1') is not null drop table #t1;
select 
    column1,
    column2 
into #t1
from tab
```

How do i implement it in SQLiteStudio?

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 statements:

```
-- delete the temp table if it exists 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp.t1;

-- create the temp table 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp.t1 AS
SELECT column1, column2
FROM tab;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7a23e4357c173d7ade1f671d6fb43531).